# how to know if php mail failed

Tags: php, email

I am sending mails from php mail() : and I want to receive a failed message if sending is failed to the destinatio .

```
$to = 'itsdfdsf@7sisters.in';
    $email_from = "info@7sisters.in";

    $full_name = 'XXXX';
    $from_mail = $full_name.'<'.$email_from.'>';



    $subject = "testing sender name";
    $message = "";
    $message .= '
            <p><strong>This is only a test mail. Please do not reply.</strong><br />
    ';
    $from = $from_mail;

    //$headers = "" .
    //         "Reply-To:" . $from . "\r\n" .
    //         "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

    $headers = "From:" . $from_mail . "\r\n" .
               "Reply-To:" . $from_mail . "\r\n" .
               "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();


    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";        

    if(!mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
    {
        echo 'failed !!';
    }
```

But although `$to` mail does no exist,it is not showing `failed !!`

Comment: If your From and Reply-To headers are set, then all you can really hope for is to receive bounces back on that address. There is also a separate `Bounces-To:` header that can be specified.

Comment: This is because after PHP hands the message off to the SMTP server to deliver, it cannot directly know the success or failure of delivery. The SMTP server won't necessarily deliver the message right away. You can only wait for bounces.

Comment: So practically there is no way to know if message to the mail failed or successful ?

Comment: That is correct. You can only know of errors that happened when handing the message to the outbound SMTP server via `mail()`. What becomes of it after that cannot be known to PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is to check for a real email not only a valid formatted email. So I would suggest you to have a look at this [blog](http://www.webdigi.co.uk/blog/2009/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-exists-without-sending-an-email/)

Answer (score 5):

The mail method is just sending the mail out. If it does not receive any errors (e.g. by not finding the server etc), it will return succesfull. You will not be able to know if the mail actually landed in the inbox of the recipient unless you create some code around bounced emails etc.

Answer (score 3):

check the return from of [`mail`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

> Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE
>   otherwise.
>
> It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for
>   delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended
>   destination.

Although the fact it is returning true probably means that your mail program is accepting the message but then failing when it tries to send to no one...

You should run the `$to` through a validator to check its a valid address and then throw an error if its not, don't rely on `mail()` to filter out things which you already know are wrong, or can check against easily.

--UPDATE

Then check out @SeRPRo , but what your trying to do is hard work to test programatically - its far easier and more reliable to send an e-mail which requires the user to click a link to verify that it's real than try querying SMTP servers which all have different behaviour (read: are broken to different degrees). Also note that your intended behaviour (code wise) is hard to differentiate from a spammers so don't be surprised to find it difficult going if you avoid the verification e-mail route.

Comment: but like in the above case `$to` is valid email but it does not exist.So I wont be able to find if mail to $to is failed?

Answer (score 1):

> But although $to mail does no exist,it is not showing failed !!

actually the fact that mail is being delivered to SMTP server, doesn't mean it will be delivered to the end user. There's no easy way in PHP to check whether it's delivered.

Answer (score 0):

You could CC yourself as a way of testing that it is leaving the outbox.

Comment: I did not get u..can you explain a bit

Answer (score 0):

In my case it helped to set the return-path via the commandline parameter "-f", which can be passed in the $additional_parameters parameter of mail(). so i call

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, "-f address.where.i.want.the.bounces@xy.com");
```

... according to some comments on http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php hosting-inviroments react different and have different restrictions (address might need to be registered in the same hosting-account, or be on the same domain, the same as the "From:" in the heade ... and so on)

The page where I got the bounces to be received (with non of the mentioned restrictions, as it seems) is hosted at Domainfactory http://www.df.eu

Answer (score 0):

Use phpmailer to send email and set $mail->AddCustomHeader('Return-path:bounce@mail.com');
This will send bounce email at bounce@mail.com if recipient mail id does not exist or recipient does not receive email by any other case.